# How to determine how many free google distance queries are left on my account?

Tags: r, google-maps, ggmap, google-distancematrix-api

I'm pulling distance/time information for a large number of origin/destination pairs using the Google Maps API in R. I'm currently using the [gmapsdistance](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gmapsdistance/gmapsdistance.pdf) package but have looked at a few others.

My premium API key includes 100k free queries per day. Are there any packages that can return how many are remaining? For example, the `ggmap` package has a `geocodeQueryCheck()`. The problem is I don't think this function actually returns the number remaining **on your account**. It doesn't ask for your API key. My guess is that it just keeps track of how many it has called today. The latest github version has a `register_google()` function that does allow you to set your API key, but when I make API requests with the `gmapsdistance` package, `geocodeQueryCheck()` doesn't update.

In summary, I just want to know how many are left. Even if I need to construct the URL address directly. When I look at the API documentation, I don't even see URL calls for it, which doesn't give me much hope.

Comment: There is no API (that I know of) for checking your quota, you have to use the developer console directly. Also, using [`library(googleway)`](https://github.com/SymbolixAU/googleway) you can set your API key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As confirmed by @SymbolixAU, there is currently no way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I guess this is late, but have you tried this?

```
sum(.GoogleDistQueryCount$elements)
```